# How do I plot from two separate subfolders in Matlab onto the same plot?

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I have 2 subfolders that I would like to plot in Matlab. They are stored as such:

C:\Users\Name\OneDrive\Desktop\Outputs\Data\Phase1\out\Stats

C:\Users\Name\OneDrive\Desktop\Outputs\Data\Phase2\out\Stats

The stats folders have 10 txt files in them numbered 1 to 10. How can I plot file '1.txt' from both subfolders on the same figure, but in the legend have the plots named Phase1 and Phase2? All files of the same number have the same dimensions. So Phase1\out\Stats\8.txt and Phase2\out\Stats\8.txt have the same dimensions. Currently the data is in a fds and hence cell array of all 20 tables that I am plotting as I go using 'cellfun'

Because there is another subfolder between Phase and Stats, should I save Stats into its respective Phase subfolder and work from there as there is other files in 'out'? Thinking ahead, what would be the easiest way to work a dropdown as later on I want to have it so all Phases will be plotted but the user can select, e.g '3.txt' a variable common to all '3.txt' files as they are all the same, and will plot that variable of all the 3.txt files.

The main problem I see is that the data from my fds is stored in a 20x1 cell array of tables but I don't know how to work it be folder, e.g. a 2x1 cell array each row containing a 10x1 array of tables. I tried changing up the legend but that loaded the full path name into the text box which covered a large percentage of the plot.

Honestly, not skilled enough at Matlab to know where to go from here.

```
Folders = dir(fullfile("C:\Users\NamE\OneDrive\Desktop\Files\Data\*\*\**\Stats\","*.txt"));

Folders = Folders(~ismember({Folders.name},{'.','..'}));

Folders_Data = struct2cell(Folders);
Folders_Data = transpose(Folders_Data);


Files_Data = struct2cell(Folders);
Files_Data = transpose(Files_Data);
Files_Data = Files_Data(:,2);
Files_Data = unique(Files_Data);

fds = fileDatastore(Files_Data, ReadFcn=@(x) readtable(x,VariableNamingRule="preserve"), FileExtensions=".txt", IncludeSubfolders=true, ReadMode="file"); 
data = readall(fds)
```

;

Comment: You can write a function that loads data from multiple places and plots it on a single plot.  There's nothing really special about where the data comes from.  Perhaps your question is really about how to display multiple data series in one plot with a legend?

Comment: I think your question needs more detail (ideally some code, even if we can't run it because we don't have the files). My impression is that there an issue where you are generically loading all text files, but then want to only plot some of them. Also, you're unsure how to have the legend only contain a bit of information, rather than the entire file path. I would just load the specific files and plot them. I'll put some very rough code in an answer ...

Comment: @Jimbo I have added some of my code that does all the reading of the files and constructs the datastore. Ideally I just want to call the 'Data' folder as it can be updated periodically with more 'Stats' subfolders

Comment: Jimbo's answer uses 2 paths to do what always has to be done 1st : import all data into the workskapce. Then Work/Process the data and export results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it ...

```
root1 = 'C:\Users\Name\OneDrive\Desktop\Outputs\Data\Phase1\out\Stats';
root2 = 'C:\Users\Name\OneDrive\Desktop\Outputs\Data\Phase2\out\Stats';

for i = 1:10
   file_name = sprintf('%d.txt',i);
   f1 = fullfile(root1,file_name);
   f2 = fullfile(root2,file_name);

   %Load both files
   data1 = ...
   data2 = ...

   figure(i)
   plot(data1)
   hold on
   plot(data2)
   hold off
   legend({'Phase1','Phase2'})
   title(sprintf('Results from file %d',i))
end
```

**Edit:** Here's something that a bit more directly answers the question. Note that the result of `dir` is a structure whereas the name `Folders` in the question implies it is a list of folders. I tend to use the variable `d` as the output from `dir`

```
d = dir(fullfile("C:\Users\NamE\OneDrive\Desktop\Files\Data\*\*\**\Stats\","*.txt"));

%This really is a folder name
folders = {d.folder};

%Find all Phase### folders
temp = regexp(folders,'Phase(\d+)','once','tokens');

n_files = length(temp);
folder_id = NaN(n_files,1);
for i = 1:length(temp)
    cur_match = temp{i};
    if ~isempty(cur_match)
       folder_id(i) = str2double(cur_match{1});
    end
end

%folder_id : holds ## for each phase
max_phase = max(folder_id);

%Shuffling data as requested
data2 = cell(1,max_phase);
for i = 1:max_phase
    data2{i} = data(folder_id == i);
end
```